# does wordpress automatically understand $post->id or do i need to set it myself

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, themes

i've set up a shortcode that will pull all child pages to the page its put on however it pulling all the pages in the site into the menu

```
function my_function() {

         $args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
 );


        $children = get_pages($args); 

        $result = "<div class='row inner'>";
        foreach ( $children as $child )
        {
            $child_id = $child->ID;
            $url  = get_permalink( $child_id );
            $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($child_id, array(240, 240));
            $title= $child->post_title;

            $link = "<a href='$url'>$thumb<div class='product-title'>$title</div></a>";

            $result .= "<div class='col-md-3 product-item'>$link</div>";
        }

        $result .= "</div>";

        return $result;
}

add_shortcode('show_child_pages', 'my_function');
```

in post_parent i have $post->id but I'm not sure if have to set this as a variable with the get_Id function i tried and it just messed the menu up more i feel like i done it wrong though. 
any help is much appreciated

this has been marked as a duplicate however my question is not answered in either

even after adding global $post; at the top of the function it still spits out all the menu items

Comment: You need to set it before using it: `global $post;`

Comment: @brasofilo ive now added above the argument global $post; $id = $post->id; however its still spitting out all the pages in the menu

Comment: Does the $post->ID works? What if you put some existant id?

Comment: ive added the id in post_parent still nothing could it be my argument?@brasofilo

Answer (score 0):

$post doesnt have any value yet, it´s inside a simple array ($args) and thats just php, $post wont have any value until you set it before.

[Function Reference/$post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post)

As you can see in the documentation above the $post ref works inside a wordpress loop

Comment: ive now added above the argument 
global $post;
$id = $post->id;     
 however its still spitting out all the pages in the menu